# How to store generic entity using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a Generic entity I want to persist using JPA so that its generic value is stored in a single `jsonb` column.
The simplified entity class look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Generic<T> {

    @Id
    private String name;

    private Type type;

    private T value; // want to store it in jsonb column

    // ... constructros, getters
}
```

The `type` uniquely identifies the class of generic value and multiple types with the same class are allowed:

```
public enum Type {

    TYPE1(Double.class),
    TYPE2(Double.class),
    TYPE3(Coordinate.class),
    ...
    TYPEN(Double.class);

    private Class<?> aClass;

    TelemetrySignal(Class<?> aClass) {
        this.aClass = aClass;
    }

    Class<?> getClass() {
        return aClass;
    }
}
```

I failed to find the way how to persist such generic class using Hibernate as is. I found alternative ways and workarounds but they do not look ideal to me.
I considered the options:

1. Mark `Generic` as abstract and annotate it with `@MappedSuperclass`, use single table inheritance and for each possible class of value create the derived class that persists the values as `json` to the same `jsonb` column and loads to the concrete class. I would choose that option for simple hierarchy but I expect a lot of classes. And extra new class of value requires new derived class for it.
2. Set the type of value as `JsonNode` and mark its type class as `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType`. In this case only one Java class is required but the drawback is that I have to interact with `JsonNode` in the rest of my code. I have to convert back and forth when the class information is required e.g. to pass it to appropriate handler.

Also I considered the options but failed to implement:

3. I tried to implement my own `org.hibernate.type.Type` and used `com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.ImmutableType` to simplify it. The idea is to look at the `type` column when handling `value` column and to deserialize the value to the corresponding class. But I failed to implement `T get(ResultSet rs, String[] names,...)` properly since I only get the name of my current column for value and cannot get the value of `type` column from the `ResultSet` (Hibernate creates aliases for all columns).
4. I tried to use two fields: `@Transient T value` and `JsonNode genericValue`. The idea was to convert the value from `@Transient T value` to `JsonNode genericValue` in `@PrePersist` method and to convert the `JsonNode` to `@Transient T value` using the `type` field the with class information in `@PostLoad` method. But it turned out that `@Transient` fields are null in `@PrePersist` methods.

Currently I have stopped on the 2nd option but I consider the 5th option: to create custom repository for this entity and to use the `JdbcTemplate` instead of Hibernate for this class only. It will be definitely possible because I can get the `type` column from the `ResultSet` and deserialize the value to the appropriate class. But I still have a chance that someone will offer the alternative option using Hibernate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

JPA provides a way to translate database into entities, but you need and extra layer to translate your database object into your desired object type.

I think that the logic of this is wrong... but anyway...

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="generic_table") // put the correct name
public class Generic {

  @Id
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "generic_type")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)   // put here the correct conf for each field
  private Type type;

  @Column(name = "generic_value")
  private binary[] value; // want to store it in jsonb column then it's a binary array for us. 


}
```

Later create a method that make the parsing:

```
public <T> T parseGeneric(class<T>, binary[] content){
  // parsing here
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is definitely a one more option that worth to consider. Looks like I was obsessed with the idea that this logic must be implemented in the repository layer. But after your answer it looks like a good idea to separate this logic into separate layer so the code is clear and obvious.